# should my program lock /etc/.pwd.lock when reading /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, passwd, shadow-database

I'm writing some program that reads /etc/{passwd,group}.

I learned that any program should lock /etc/.pwd.lock by calling lckpwdf() before writing the above files so that write collisions can be avoided.

I guess reading operation also needs this lock so that program won't read out inconsistent data.

But I found I can't do the lock when reading /etc/passwd as non-root, because /etc/.pwd.lock is owned by root:root and has mode 0600.

Am I wrong? Doesn't reading need this lock?

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, `lckpwdf()` is declared in `<shadow.h>` and should be used when accessing the shadow password database (`/etc/shadow`). It does not need to be called when reading `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group`.

Since it's a nonstandard function, this is not necessarily the case on other UNIXes.